# Dynamically re-sizable bar charts with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, charts

Does anyone have any recommendations for a JavaScript charting library that allows a user to update bar charts dynamically?

What i mean by this is that a user enters data, generates the bar chart and then is able to resize the bar plots themselves whilst dynamically updating the value of the plot.

Comment: Please clarify your question, title & tags.  In the title and tags, you are only asking for a jQuery solution.  However, in the question, you are asking for any JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

highcharts.com do a great charting library you should be able to use.

Comment: That's pure JavaScript.  The question title/tags are asking for a jQuery solution.

Comment: JavaScript would be fine as well to be honest.  the main requirement is that the bar chart plots are resizable really.  Have looked but cannot find.